# How to process emails with attachment using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, outlook

My ultimate goal is to open files that are sent to an email account, process data in those files and upload the data into a database. I am stuck at the first stage. I can't open and process the email message from Outlook. I've never worked with emails programmatically, so my understanding of email data structures is very poor.

I saved an email from MS Outlook containing some text and an attachment on a drive. Then I tried opening it using Python 2.7:

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_file(open('test with attachment.msg'))
print msg.is_multipart()
```

`is_mulitipart` returns False

`msg.get_payload()` returns blank.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't it be a multipart message with text? How should I process this email?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!